# Mousewheel scroll event fire only once per scroll-session

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, touchpad

I am trying to mimic the functionality of the following website: www.verbaasd.net. Each scrolling "session" will only trigger one action.

Each time a user scrolls down an action will happen depending on the status of variabel count. I only want this to happen ONCE per scroll. For example if a user has a Macbook with touchpad it will fire multiple times very vast. The count will go from 1 to 4 pretty much instantly. Is there a way to set a timeout or something so it stops for 0.5 sec when variabel count increases or decreases by 1?

Current code:

```
var count = 1;

$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    count -= 1;
  } else {
    count += 1;
  }
  if (count < 1) count = 1;
  if (count > 4) count = 4;

    switch (count) {
    case 1:
      // do something
      break;
    case 2:
      // do something
      break;
    case 3:
      // do something
      break;
    case 4:
      // do something
      break;
  }

  $(".cd-background-wrapper").attr("data-slide", count);

});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860108/jquery-page-scroll-event-logic-how-to-throttle

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't get Underscore to work but lodash is working nicely. Thanks!

Comment: I have an answer here that doesn't require an entire library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822077/scroll-function-firing-multiple-times-instead-of-once/34822169#34822169

Answer (score 1):

I recommend other way.

You should use 'preventDefault' and delay effect using setTimeout.

I wrote a simple prototype code below link. 
(only tested on Chrome and safari)

http://codepen.io/nigayo/pen/PNEvmY

[HTML]

```
 <body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <section>section A</section>
    <section>section B</section>
    <section>section C</section>
    <section>section D</section>
  </div>
</body>
```

[CSS]

```
 body {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 100%;
 }

 #wrap {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
 }

 section {
   width: 100%;
   height: 600px;
 }

 section:nth-child(1) {
   background: red;
 }
 section:nth-child(2) {
   background: blue;
 }

 section:nth-child(3) {
   background: green;
 }
 section:nth-child(4) {
   background: magenta;
 }
```

[JavaScript]

```
(function() {
  var currentPanel = 1;
  var wrap = $('#wrap');
  var panelsize = 600;
  var step = 10;
  var interval = 1000;
  var direction = 1;

  var bAnimation = false;

  function animation() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var currentTop = parseInt(wrap.css("top"));

      if (direction < 0) {
        if (currentTop <= minValue) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            bAnimation = false;
          }, interval);
          return;
        }
      } else {
        if (currentTop >= minValue) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            bAnimation = false;
          }, interval);
          return;
        }
      }

      wrap.css({
        "top": currentTop - step
      });
      animation();
    }, 16);
  }

  $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (bAnimation) return;

    var currentTop = parseInt(wrap.css("top"));

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
      //down scroll
      minValue = currentTop - panelsize;
      step = 10;
      direction = -1;
    } else {
      //up scroll
      minValue = currentTop + panelsize;
      step = -10;
      direction = 1;
    }

    console.log(minValue, bAnimation);
    bAnimation = true;
    animation();
  });
})();
```

If you refer to my codes, you should use 'jquery animate function' or 'requestAnimationframe' for animation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Answer thanks to A. Wolff. Using _.throttle with lodash.js did the trick! You can find more info here: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/