# Is there a way to 'bake' the variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating dynamic scroll page, where I decided to use `wheel` event to detect user's scrolling. As you may know this event has a `deltaY` parameter that updates dynamically(several times for one scroll). I want the script to return `true` once `deltaY` is bigger than 100. However it updates over and over again causing my function shoot several times. Is there a way to 'bake'(be able to change once) this `true` value?

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', func)

function func(event){
  if(event.deltaY>100){
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var text = document.createTextNode("You scrolled over 100"); 
    p.appendChild(text);
    document.body.insertBefore(p, document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]);
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Scroll the page down \/ and keep scrolling</p>
```

Comment: You may provide some code? At least your attempt which isn't working properly.

Comment: Do you want a function that executes _once_ when a condition is met?

Comment: @vlaz Yes. Once delta is bigger than 100.

Comment: look in to scroll throttling/debouncing (https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)

Comment: or maybe this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860108/jquery-page-scroll-event-logic-how-to-throttle

Comment: You know it's a delta-value. it's only over 100 when you scroll really fast ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c7yxxp0y/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fwxkx3u4/

Comment: @adeneo Thanks! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the listener once the element has been added. this way the function will not continue to fire.

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', func)

function func(event){
  if(event.deltaY>100){
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var text = document.createTextNode("You scrolled over 100"); 
    p.appendChild(text);
    document.body.insertBefore(p, document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]);
    window.removeEventListener('wheel',func);
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener